# Adding a 'Label' control to a 'RichTextBox'

Tags: c#, label, richtextbox

I'm having trouble adding a `Label` control to a `RichTextBox`. Clearly, there must be something that I'm missing in the code. I would appreciate it if someone could point out my omission. I know both of the controls are created, but the `Label` is not displayed on top of the `RichTexBox`...instead, it's created *behind* it.

```
RichTextBox richBox8;
Label label8;

private void create()
{
    richBox8 = new RichTextBox();
    richBox8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(957, 95);
    richBox8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 50);
    richBox8.Name = "richTextBox8";
    Controls.Add(richBox8);

    label8 = new Label();
    label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(984, 106);
    label8.Name = "label8";
    label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 25);
    label8.Text = ""
    Controls.Add(label8);
    richBox8.Controls.Add(label8);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general all you have to do is **add a text value** to your label! And you should pay attention to the x-y coordinates for each of your controls.

```
RichTextBox richBox8 = null;
Label label8 = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richBox8 = new RichTextBox();
    richBox8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
    richBox8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
    richBox8.Name = "richTextBox8";
    Controls.Add(richBox8);

    label8 = new Label();
    label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
    label8.Name = "label8";
    label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 25);
    label8.Text = "hello world";  // crucial, if there is no text, you won't see any label!
    richBox8.Controls.Add(label8);
    // adding the label once again to the form.Controls collection is unnecessary
}
```

And although it is ***possible*** **to add a label to a `RichTextBox`** control, I don't think it is very useful! A `RichTextBox` can be used to *display* and *format text*:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    richTextBox1.Text = "demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text ";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Select(10, 20);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;

    richTextBox1.Select(25, 30);
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12);
}
```

Comment: Various projects require various tasks. I'm experimenting with richTextBoxes and labels, thus I needed to know how they work together. Thanks for your answer, very helpul.